# OAuth Authorization Service in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, oauth, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In Web API 2, you used to be able to create an endpoint to issue a token by setting up an OAuth Authorization Server via middleware like below:

```
//Set up our auth server options.
var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

 // Sets up the token issue endpoint using the options above
 app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
```

Perhaps I'm missing it, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this in ASP.NET Core.  I've looked through the source (https://github.com/aspnet/Security) but I don't really see anything analogous.  Is there a new way to accomplish this?  Do I need to just create a controller and do it myself?

I see how OAuth Authentication can be set up via Middleware, but this regards the authorization portion where I issue claims from my API.

Comment: perhaps this could help. it's an answer with thinktecture's identity server : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360563/asp-net-5-oauth-bearer-token-authentication/29487480#29487480

Comment: Thanks @CedricDumont, I was looking for something integrated, but I've considered Thinktecture.  End of day that may be what I go with.  It's very solid.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

EDIT (01/28/2021): AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server has been merged into [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) as part of the 3.0 update. To get started with OpenIddict, visit [documentation.openiddict.com](https://documentation.openiddict.com/).

---

Don't waste your time looking for an `OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware` alternative in ASP.NET Core, the ASP.NET team simply decided not to port it: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/83

I suggest having a look to **AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server**, an advanced fork of the OAuth2 authorization server middleware that comes with Katana 3: there's an OWIN/Katana 3 version, and an ASP.NET Core version that supports both the full .NET framework and .NET Core.

https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

**ASP.NET Core 1.x:**

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
{
    options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
    options.TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token");
    options.AccessTokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.TokenEndpointPath = "/token";
    options.Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider();
});
```

**ASP.NET Core 2.x:**

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
{
    options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
    options.TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token");
    options.AccessTokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.TokenEndpointPath = "/token";
    options.Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider();
});
```

To learn more about this project, I'd recommend reading http://kevinchalet.com/2016/07/13/creating-your-own-openid-connect-server-with-asos-introduction/.

Good luck!

Comment: This is really what I was looking for...perhaps this question will help other people find this project.  Thanks to those working on this!

Comment: You're welcome! It's still a young project, but I hope to release a RC version soon on NuGet.org (I still need to introduce a few breaking branches in the vNext version, that I also want to backport to OWIN/Katana 3, so it might need a few weeks more). Don't hesitate to ping me here, on GitHub or on JabbR if you have any question or if you want to share your feedback ;)

Comment: @Pinpoint, you've been doing some impressive work there! I managed to build out a token provider using the default packages, and detailed it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29698502/195653, but I feel like the OpenIdConnect server is probably the better way to go!

Comment: older question, but you might want to also check out IdentityServer4 - it just entered beta for Asp.Net Core http://leastprivilege.com/2016/01/11/announcing-identityserver-for-asp-net-5-and-net-core/

Comment: Can I implement same functionality in .NET core 2.0, I tried but getting error TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthenticationOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Comment: The AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server project hasn't been updated in almost a year, so it seems to have been abandoned. The same author seems to have replaced it with https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core.

Comment: @computercarguy OpenIddict 1.x/.2x uses AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server (aka ASOS) internally. Starting with 3.0, ASOS will indeed be merged into OpenIddict (it's still a WIP). More information there: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/736

Comment: can this be made to work with asp.net core on .net 6?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still looking for the original OAuth Authorization Server in ASP.NET 5, I have ported the code and the original sample here:
    https://github.com/XacronDevelopment/oauth-aspnet

The port includes backwards compatibility to allow ASP.NET 4.x resource servers to read the access tokens created by the authorization server.

The nuget packages are here:
    https://www.nuget.org/packages/OAuth.AspNet.AuthServer
    https://www.nuget.org/packages/OAuth.AspNet.Tokens
    https://www.nuget.org/packages/OAuth.Owin.Tokens

Comment: Katana's authorization server had many unsolved bugs, still listed on the Codeplex tracker. I took a brief look at your fork and it seems that you've fixed none of them. If you're still looking for the "original authorization server", take a look at `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server`, it offers the same experience but fixes all the known bugs Katana's server had.