# ASP.NET 5 OAuth bearer token authentication

Tags: asp.net, oauth, owin, asp.net-core

I’m trying to implement OAuth bearer token authentication in ASP.NET 5 and am struggling to find an example of how to do this because the OWIN stuff has changed in ASP.NET 5.

For example **IApplicationBuilder.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer()** and **IApplicationBuilder. UseOAuthBearerAuthentication()** either don’t exist anymore or I’m missing a reference?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I did it work, but with setting up **Thinktecture's identity server v 3** as my token provider but I think if you have another token provider it will be the same flow....

(update : I added a github repo with the code : [here](https://github.com/CedricDumont/vnext-playground/tree/master/idsrv3-vnext/idsrv3))

here is my startup class: (Identityserver v3 also runs on Vnext with some little tweaking). notice I have the server and the web api in same web app. it's also ok if you have two different web project but here it's for the sake of demo...

```
public class Startup
{
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/core", core =>
        {
            var factory = InMemoryFactory.Create(
                                    users: Users.Get(),
                                    clients: Clients.Get(),
                                    scopes: Scopes.Get());

            var idsrvOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                IssuerUri = "https://idsrv3.com",
                SiteName = "test vnext Identity server",
                Factory = factory,
                SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(),
                RequireSsl = false,

                CorsPolicy = CorsPolicy.AllowAll,

                AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
                {
                }
            };

            core.UseIdentityServer(idsrvOptions);
        });

        app.Map("/api", api =>
        {

            api.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(options => {
                options.Authority = Constants.AuthorizationUrl;
                options.MetadataAddress = Constants.AuthorizationUrl + "/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = "https://idsrv3.com/resources"; 
            });

            api.UseMvc();

        });

    }
}
```

from here you can see that my IdentityServerV3 is mapped to '/core' and in the same web app project (it could be another one), I have an web api that uses MVC. below is the controller:

```
  [Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class Test : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            message = "You See this then it's ok auth is  :" + User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
        });
    }
}
```

I have configure a Client in my identity server :

```
  new Client
            {
                 //Resource Owner Flow Client (our web UI)
                ClientName = "WebUI",
                Enabled = true,

                ClientId = "IdentityWebUI",
                ClientSecrets = new List<ClientSecret>
                {
                    new ClientSecret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600

            }
```

and here is the User (used InMemory user):

```
 return new List<InMemoryUser>
        {
            new InMemoryUser
            {
                Username = "testUser",
                Password = "testPwd",
                Subject = "I am the Subject"
            }

        };
```

In fidler I issue the following POST to get a bearer token:

```
    POST : http://localhost:4357/core/connect/token

    User-Agent: Fiddler
    Host: localhost:4357
    Content-Length: 67
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Authorization: Basic SWRlbnRpdHlXZWJVSTpzZWNyZXQ=

    grant_type=password&username=testUser&password=testPwd&scope=openid
```

in the response you will get an Access_token

```
{"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImEzck1VZ01Gdjl0UGNsTGE2eUYzekFrZnF1RSIsImtpZCI6ImEzck1VZ01Gdjl0UGNsTGE2eUYzekFrZnF1RSJ9.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJJZGVudGl0eVdlYlVJIiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQiLCJzdWIiOiJJIGFtIHRoZSBTdWJqZWN0IiwiYW1yIjoicGFzc3dvcmQiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE0MjgzOTQ3MzAsImlkcCI6Imlkc3J2IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9pZHNydjMuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9pZHNydjMuY29tL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImV4cCI6MTQyODM5ODMzMCwibmJmIjoxNDI4Mzk0NzMwfQ.cbB4YrRXaaRDNw8BjeI4Q1DvXN28xmJScMJBGWCM_zSLcH1i63cQVTmR8X86rGP5VrR0Ly4-EmWZ8911Vh4jc4Ua0Kgz2n7RbmQ6VqQX5Z_lM3F8EIgD81kpUn0v3hhSFW06aJ2Lo1XOZG_re84xGgqre-H4dC0XZR6IQMEAQ9Q5dOXBh8V1NxyLSh0PzyrRRmOnEndoaY4uaIFtbp9j7KnXxQ3ZdGmaYAO96xuhHfO1DbgRdw6fYyf4nnC795yhnwDh1QZGxPsFaysJSA_3-cjmw-29m-Ga0hD1ALfVE7R57iNLxkB6dyEuz1UFJhJyibRDW9sNspo2gQFZZGxMKQ","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

then I use that access_token to call my web api

here is the fiddler (in composer pane)

```
    GET http://localhost:4357/api/Test

    User-Agent: Fiddler
    Host: localhost:4357
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImEzck1VZ01Gdjl0UGNsTGE2eUYzekFrZnF1RSIsImtpZCI6ImEzck1VZ01Gdjl0UGNsTGE2eUYzekFrZnF1RSJ9.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJJZGVudGl0eVdlYlVJIiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQiLCJzdWIiOiJJIGFtIHRoZSBTdWJqZWN0IiwiYW1yIjoicGFzc3dvcmQiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE0MjgzOTQ3MzAsImlkcCI6Imlkc3J2IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9pZHNydjMuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9pZHNydjMuY29tL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImV4cCI6MTQyODM5ODMzMCwibmJmIjoxNDI4Mzk0NzMwfQ.cbB4YrRXaaRDNw8BjeI4Q1DvXN28xmJScMJBGWCM_zSLcH1i63cQVTmR8X86rGP5VrR0Ly4-EmWZ8911Vh4jc4Ua0Kgz2n7RbmQ6VqQX5Z_lM3F8EIgD81kpUn0v3hhSFW06aJ2Lo1XOZG_re84xGgqre-H4dC0XZR6IQMEAQ9Q5dOXBh8V1NxyLSh0PzyrRRmOnEndoaY4uaIFtbp9j7KnXxQ3ZdGmaYAO96xuhHfO1DbgRdw6fYyf4nnC795yhnwDh1QZGxPsFaysJSA_3-cjmw-29m-Ga0hD1ALfVE7R57iNLxkB6dyEuz1UFJhJyibRDW9sNspo2gQFZZGxMKQ
```

Then I get the response still in fidler:

you can have more info by following this [link](http://cedric-dumont.com/tutorials/identityserver-v3-membershipreboot-angularjs-webapi-2-and-mvc-mix-it-introduction/identityserver-v3-membershipreboot-angularjs-webapi-2-and-mvc-mix-it-part-1/) below, but it's not related to vnext. I will create a post on this as I need an angularJS app to authenticate and use an implicit flow instead of resource owner flow... with visual studio 2015 preview

Comment: I'm interested in reading your post on AngularJS, Oauth implicit flow, with VS 2015.  Is this posted somewhere?

Comment: "Identityserver v3 also runs on Vnext with some little tweaking".  Please can you provide more info on this because I can't seem to resolve the dependencies

Comment: @MRainzo See the sample ASP.NET 5 project implementing Identity Server 3 here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNet5Host

Comment: in your POST request, what is `Authorization: Basic SWRlbnRpdHlXZWJVSTpzZWNyZXQ=`  - where did that come from?
`

Comment: it's just basic authentication with user password encoded : username:password encoded in base64. You can do this with fiddler. check it's documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure where **UseOAuthAuthorizationServer** is, but for **UseOAuthBearerAuthentication**, try adding the Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OAuthBearer NuGet Package and then in your startup Configure Method add:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Audience = {your audience};
                options.Authority = {your authority}}); //or whatever options you need
```

Comment: FYI, the OAuth2 authorization server that was part of Katana won't be ported to ASP.NET 5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055477/oauth-authorization-service-in-asp-net-mvc-6/29144031#29144031

Answer (score 2):

The real kicker here is the token generation. I've managed to build one using the default `Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OAuthBearer` package, but it wasn't easy.

```
// Injected from the constructor; this is why we configured the options above rather 
// than simply passing them to the UseOAuthBearerAuthentication()
private readonly OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions bearerOptions;

// In your /Token action...
var handler = bearerOptions.SecurityTokenValidators.OfType<System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler>()
    .First();
// The identity here is the ClaimsIdentity you want to authenticate the user as.
// You can get this using the SignInManager if you're using Identity.
var securityToken = handler.CreateToken(
    issuer: bearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer, 
    audience: bearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience, 
    subject: identity);
var token = handler.WriteToken(securityToken);
// The var token is your bearer token
```

My full solution is detailed here: [Token Based Authentication in ASP.Net 5 (vNext)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29698502/195653).