# AddDefaultTokenProviders: what is it and how to use those "default providers"?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I found this in my `Startup.cs` file in `ConfigureServices` in a default Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET 5 project:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthorizationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

What does it exactly do, and how to use those "default providers"? Does it configure all token-based authentication for me? Where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Despite their name, the token providers have nothing to do with token authentication: they are exclusively used to generate opaque tokens for account operations (like password reset or email change) and two-factor authentication.

There are currently 3 built-in providers:

- [`DataProtectorTokenProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/DataProtectionTokenProvider.cs): as the name suggests, it uses the data protection block (machine keys' equivalent in ASP.NET Core 1.0) to serialize encrypted tokens that can later be deserialized by the server.
- [`EmailTokenProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/EmailTokenProvider.cs) and [`PhoneNumberTokenProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/PhoneNumberTokenProvider.cs): these providers are derived from [`TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs), which implements the `Time-based One-time Password Algorithm` (TOTP), a protocol designed to produce user-friendly and short tokens that can be sent in a SMS or in an email.

ASP.NET Core 1.0 doesn't offer native token authentication support (only token validation is supported: you can't produce your own tokens). You can read these SO posts for more information:

- [Simple JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35310717/542757).
- [Web API Authentication in ASP.NET 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30681843/542757).
- [Configure the authorization server endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30857524/542757).

Comment: How about using an `IUserTokenProvider` for generating JWT refresh tokens - which can be just opaque tokens. Just wondering if this would be a good fit..

Comment: Here'a a good post on the topic https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-identity-token-providers