# How to generate token in implementation of IUserTokenProvider in Identity 3?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, access-token, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to implement **IUserTokenProvider** interface to register in Identity system and use further for authentication.
Why token authentication because i write **Web Api** server in **Asp Net Core** using **Identity 3**.
The obstacle is i don't know how to generate token. **IUserTokenProvider** has 2 method i need: 1. generates token 2. validates token.
what do i write inside them? what's algorithm?

```
public class UserTokenProvider : IUserTokenProvider<AppUser>
{
    public Task<bool> CanGenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(UserManager<AppUser> manager, AppUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<string> GenerateAsync(string purpose, UserManager<AppUser> manager, AppUser user)
    {
        /* here logic to generate token */
        string result = "generated token";
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
    public Task<bool> ValidateAsync(string purpose, string token, UserManager<AppUser> manager, AppUser user)
    {
        /* validating token */
        if (token == "generated token")
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        else return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
}
```

and in **ConfigureServices** method of StartUp class i register my provider:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
            .AddTokenProvider<UserTokenProvider>("AuthToken") 
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35446819/542757), `IUserTokenProvider` has absolutely nothing to do with token authentication.

I'd recommend reading these other questions for more information about how you can issue your own access tokens in ASP.NET Core:

- [Simple JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35310717/542757).
- [Web API Authentication in ASP.NET 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30681843/542757).
- [Configure the authorization server endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30857524/542757).