# Using Claims with OpenIdConnect.Server in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

In the past 7 days I've tried to setup an ASP.NET 5 WebApi using `OpenIdConnect.Server` with the resource owner flow.

I was more or less successful in generating a token and accessing `[Authorize]` protected actions.

However, when I try to access `this.User.Identity.Claims`, it's empty. I am using ASP.NET 5, beta6 for now (having troubles upgrading to most recent beta7 and waiting for it's official release)

In the Startup.cs I got the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCaching();

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<AuthContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));
        });

    services.AddIdentity<AuthUser, AuthRole>(
        options => options.User = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserOptions
        {
            RequireUniqueEmail = true,
            UserNameValidationRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9@_\\.-]+$"
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthContext, Guid>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.ConfigureCors(configure =>
    {
        configure.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http:/localhost/", "http://win2012.bludev.com/");
        });
    });

    services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
}

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var factory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
        factory.AddConsole();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://win2012.bludev.com/api/auth/";
            options.Audience = "http://win2012.bludev.com/";

            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
                NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,

                ValidateActor = true,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateSignature = true,

                ValidAudience = "http://win2012.bludev.com/",
                ValidIssuer = "http://win2012.bludev.com/"
            };
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = new Uri("http://win2012.bludev.com/api/auth/");
            options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
            options.AuthorizationEndpointPath = PathString.Empty;
            options.Provider = new AuthorizationProvider();
            options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;

            // Note: in a real world app, you'd probably prefer storing the X.509 certificate
            // in the user or machine store. To keep this sample easy to use, the certificate
            // is extracted from the Certificate.pfx file embedded in this assembly.
            options.UseCertificate(
                assembly: typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
                resource: "AuthExample.Certificate.pfx",
                password: "Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server");
        });

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

I used `app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` because I couldn't get `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` working, all I would get is this in the console:

> request: /admin/user/ warning :
>   [Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthentica
>   tionMiddleware] OIDCH_0004: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler:
>   message.State is  null or empty. request:
>   /.well-known/openid-configuration warning :
>   [Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthentica
>   tionMiddleware] OIDCH_0004: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler:
>   message.State is  null or empty.

and an Exception after the time out

> error   : [Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.MessagePump]
>   ProcessRequestAsync System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable
>   to create to obtain configura tion from:
>   'http://win2012.bludev.com/api/auth/.well-known/openid-configuration'
>   .    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.LogHelper.Throw(String
>   message, Type excep tionType, EventLevel logLevel, Exception
>   innerException)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.d__24.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
>   ification(Task task)
>   ...

With this configuration `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AuthenticationScheme = OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.Authority = "http://win2012.bludev.com/api/auth/";
    options.Audience = "http://win2012.bludev.com/";
    options.Resource = "http://win2012.bludev.com/";

    options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        RequireSignedTokens = true,
        RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
        NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,

        ValidateActor = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateSignature = true
    };

});
```

So the real question is:

1. How to get resource owner flow to work with claims
2. `ValidateLifetime = true` or `ValidateAudience = true` would throw exception and result in a Http Code 500 response without a printed error.
3. How to turn authentication failures into a meaningful 400/403 code and a json or xml respones (depending on the client preference) to be displayed for the user? (JavaScript is the client in this case)?

Comment: The `InvalidOperationException` is caused by the fact there's no server at `http://win2012.bludev.com/api/auth/`. When the OAuth2 bearer middleware tries to download the provider's configuration metadata, it crashes and returns an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()` (which relies on `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware`) is only meant to support interactive flows (code/implicit/hybrid) and cannot be used with the resource owner password credentials grant type. Since you only want to validate access tokens, use `app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication()` instead.

See this SO answer for more information about the different OpenID Connect/OAuth2 middleware in ASP.NET 5: [Configure the authorization server endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768015/configure-the-authorization-server-endpoint/30788109#30788109)

> How to get resource owner flow to work with claims

The entire `OpenIdConnectServerMiddleware` you're using is based on claims.

If you have trouble serializing specific claims, remember that all claims except `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` are not serialized by default in the identity and access tokens, since they are both readable by the client application and the user agent. To avoid leaking confidential data, you need to specify an explicit `destination` indicating where you want the claims to be serialized:

```
// This claim will be only serialized in the access token.
identity.AddClaim(ClaimTypes.Name, username, OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);

// This claim will be serialized in both the identity and the access tokens.
identity.AddClaim(ClaimTypes.Surname, "Doe",
    OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
    OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken););
```

---

> ValidateLifetime = true or ValidateAudience = true would throw exception and result in a Http Code 500 response without a printed error.
>
> How to turn authentication failures into a meaningful 400/403 code and a json or xml respones (depending on the client preference) to be displayed for the user? (JavaScript is the client in this case)?

That's how the OIDC client middleware (managed by MSFT) currently works by default, but it will be eventually fixed. You can see this GitHub ticket a workaround: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/411

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm. Before I used `identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));`. Assuming I'd have a higher number of claims (organized by groups like `Users` and actions `Create`, `Update`, `AssignRoles` etc) and don't want to put them all in the jwt token (for both token size and confidentiality) but still need them server sided for authorizatoin, would I have to create a Middleware that fetches them from the server (or Redis cache)? Or what's the way to go