# How to create a ClaimIdentity in asp.net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

In old asp.net identity 2.0, there is a CreateIdentityAsync() method in type Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager. But now asp.net 5 has removed this method, how can I create a ClaimsIdentity representing the user now? Thanks in advance.

```
public virtual Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentityAsync(TUser user, string authenticationType);
```

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514997/usermanager-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-createidentity/33531281#33531281.

Comment: Hi @Pinpoint , thank you. I got this question when using your AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server. It's a great project. The problem is when I use the method in your answer, please see below. I found the identity.Name is null. Why it is null? How to fix this?Sorry I cannot add the comment in your answer in another question since I'm a new so user. 
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user), OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

Comment: Hey (and thanks for the kind word!). By default, `ClaimsIdentity.Name` uses the `ClaimTypes.Name` claim, so make sure you explicitly add it since `GetClaimsAsync` will unlikely add it for you (it basically only returns custom claims). When using `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`, it's automatically done for you by Identity: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#L92.

Comment: Hi @Pinpoint. yes the 'UserClaimsPrincipalFacotry' works, it can get the 'ClaimsIdentity' now. But on the OAtuh client('UseJwtBearerAuthentication') after authenticated the user, the identity.Name is still null.. Can you help me?

Comment: Don't forget that `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server` will refuse to serialize the claims that don't explicitly specify a destination, to avoid leaking confidential data in potentially readable tokens. You can find more information on this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299131/using-claims-with-openidconnect-server-in-asp-net-5/32299781. If you need a code sample demonstrating how you can specify an existing principal, don't hesitate to open a separate question and I'll post a complete snippet.

Comment: Hi @Pinpoint, I asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797838/how-to-specify-the-destination-for-an-existing-claimsidentity , can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://aspnet-docs-example.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Identity/IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory-TUser/

IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory Interface

Provides an abstraction for a factory to create a System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal from a user.

Answer (score 0):

This has been changed to UserManager.CreateAsync and returns an IdentityResult indicating whether or not the new user was successfully created.

If you want to add Claims, you can do this via UserManager.AddClaimAsync.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://moumitintech.blogspot.in/2015/08/basic-of-wifrole-based-authorization-in.html) you can find how to work with `ClaimIdentity` example with a sample `downloadable project`