# What is the difference between ASP.NET Identity and IdentityServer?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-identity-3

I can not understand the difference between the two, ASP.NET Identy is based on OWIN and does not introduce a middleware while IdentityServer introduced him, I'm confused ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Identity and IdentityServer connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219662/asp-net-identity-and-identityserver-connection)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity is a user store/identity management library. It includes some OWIN helper classes to hook into the OWIN security middleware, but otherwise has nothing to do with authentication.

IdentityServer is an OpenID Connect provider, that acts as a central authentication server for multiple applications. It has nothing to do with user storage or identity management.

Comment: Basically this. ASP.NET is a membership system with a built in host of libraries to help you integrate your user store(s) with how principals and identity works within ASP.NET.

IDS is an implementation of the OpenID Connect protocol as an authentication provider.

Comment: Thanks I finally understood!

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/all-this-microsoft-membership-identity-stuff-whats-it-about-4db18dccd9d8