# How do I avoid using Microsofts's Microsoft.AspNet.Identity package when using openiddict

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, aspnet-contrib, openiddict

I am following this brilliant tutorial http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/
It works perfectly. The problem is, is that I want to use my own user management code to validate the given username, password to retrieve an access token and refresh token.
This tutorial (and the samples on https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/tree/dev/samples) use the proprietary `Asp.net Identity` library
How would I configure the configuration given in the Startup.cs class to use my own User Managment code?
For example....

```
var user = _repo.getUsers().Where(u => u.username == req.username && req.password == u.password).FirstOrDefault();and password against whatever system you wish.
            return getAuthToken(user);
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your Startup.cs. By just removing Identity from Startup and project dependecies you should find a way I think.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: as of beta1, OpenIddict no longer depends on ASP.NET Identity**, though it's still the recommended membership stack.

---

TL;DR: you can't.

OpenIddict has been specially designed to use ASP.NET Identity's abstractions and cannot be used independently.

When using your own membership stack, I recommend using [ASOS](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server), the OpenID Connect server middleware behind OpenIddict: it doesn't depend on a particular implementation and offers full flexibility.

Here's how you could implement the resource owner password credentials grant with ASOS beta4 (for ASP.NET 5 RC1): https://stackoverflow.com/a/30857524/542757.