# Is OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider availabe in asp.net core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

Due to unavailability of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider in .net core, I created a class library in .net framework 4.7 and implemented OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider as an Authorization server. But now as .net core 2.1 has been released, I want to know whether OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider is available or still unavailable.
I have tried found this thing on google but didn't get any good results. There is another question [OAuth Authorization Service in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055477/oauth-authorization-service-in-asp-net-core) like this but that was asked more that 3 years before and I am asking in context of .Net Core 2.1
Thanks

Comment: The questioned which you mentioned was asked more than 3 years before. And I am asking this question in context of .Net Core 2.1. This is how my question is different. I am asking whether OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider is available in .Net core or not?

Comment: The fact it was asked 3 years doesn't change anything. I try to keep all my SO answers up-to-date and my answer was recently updated to include a code snippet for 2.x. So no, `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` is not available in 2.1 and the ASP.NET team doesn't have any plan to ever port it.

Comment: @Pinpoint, thanks for the answer. I have asked another question on SO related to ASOS. Can you answer that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415026/oauthauthorizationprovide-vs-aspnet-security-openinconnect

Answer (score 0):

I will point you to the Core 2.1 documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.oauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Have a look, I am sure you can find what you are looking for in there.