# OAuthAuthorizationProvide vs Aspnet.security.openinconnect

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

I have tried implementing ASOS with .net core 2.1 and there were few things which were available in OAuthAuthorizationProvider but I couldn't find them in ASOS. Also I think the context is little different in ASOS, So is there any alternate of the following code in ASOS:

```
 OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
            var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString(AuthorizePath),
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(TokenPath),
                ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
#if DEBUG
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
#endif
                // Authorization server provider which controls the lifecycle of Authorization Server
                Provider = new OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
                {
                    OnValidateClientRedirectUri = ValidateClientRedirectUri,
                    OnValidateClientAuthentication = ValidateClientAuthentication,
                    OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials = GrantResourceOwnerCredentials,
                    OnGrantClientCredentials = GrantClientCredetails
                },

                // Authorization code provider which creates and receives authorization code
                AuthorizationCodeProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
                {
                    OnCreate = CreateAuthenticationCode,
                    OnReceive = ReceiveAuthenticationCode,
                },

                // Refresh token provider which creates and receives referesh token
                RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
                {
                    OnCreate = CreateRefreshToken,
                    OnReceive = ReceiveRefreshToken,
                }
               ,

            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
```

Update:

```
private Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(context.UserName, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType), context.Scope.Select(x => new Claim("claim", x)));

    context.Validated(identity);

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

private Task GrantClientCredetails(OAuthGrantClientCredentialsContext context)
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(context.ClientId, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType), context.Scope.Select(x => new Claim("claim", x)));

    context.Validated(identity);

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the options are still there but the events model has been reworked:

- `OnValidateClientRedirectUri` was replaced by a more general `OnValidateAuthorizationRequest` event.
- `OnValidateClientAuthentication` no longer exists. Client authentication validation is now performed in the `OnValidateTokenRequest` event (or `OnValidateIntrospectionRequest`/`OnValidateRevocationRequest`, but you're not using the introspection/revocation endpoints in your snippet).
- The `*Provider` properties - used for decrypting/encrypting tokens - have been replaced by `Serialize*` and `Deserialize*` events. Using them is no longer mandatory: in this case, authorization codes and refresh tokens will be considered valid until they expire.

If you want to learn more about the revamped events model, don't miss this blog post series: https://kevinchalet.com/2016/07/13/creating-your-own-openid-connect-server-with-asos-introduction/

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have edited my question under Update: section, can you tell me how can I add these claims in ASOS. I have tried but got no luck. Also how can we handle refresh tokens? I can see refresh token in response but I didn't handle it myself