# Handling multiple client accessing ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Right now I'm using jwt as authentication and authorization. I have 2 clients which are a web and a mobile app. When the user logs in to the web app, he will get an access token for that web client, and when the same user logs in to the mobile app, he will get an access token for that mobile app.

Therefore if one of the clients is logged out by the user, the other client shouldn't log out, too. The way I know the user is logged in from different client is I save the refresh token in the database with the `clientid`, just want to know is this still correct practice. because I am confused about identityserver, OAuth 2.0

My expectation is my Web API can handle authorization for multiple clients

Comment: From the point of view of the API, there's no "being logged in" notion - each call is separate, standalone - and for each call, the API will check the bearer token sent along, to determine if that call can go through (or not). Being "logged in" is more of a frontend concern - the API really doesn't care - it just checks the bearer token (whether it's valid or expired etc.) and either allows (and processes) the call - or it refuses to do so

Comment: i get that, i just confused which kind of auth should i use. i have done my research on identityserver(which has convert to duende), openiddict, OAuth 2.0. some said i should not do my own authentication logic. and also i just saw someone do sql injection on jwt token. Really apreciate more insight on this. ps* im still new in doing web api

Comment: The current "Best Practice" probably really is **OAuth2** - so you have an external identity provider (IdentityServer, Azure AD or whatever) to handle authentication, and they provide an access token (in the form of a JSON web token JWT) to authenticate your calls. Which product is used to provide this authentication mechanism and create the access tokens is less relevant - just stick with the OAuth 2 standard (and yes - **definitely** do **NOT** roll your own! )

Comment: is it based on the flagged answered for this question, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73658327/how-to-implement-oauth2-0-authentication-token-in-asp-net-core-web-api)? when i go to the blog mentioned, its almost same with my current jwt method which i follow this refference (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5325297/Apply-JWT-Access-Tokens-and-Refresh-Tokens-in-ASP)