# Identity Server, JWT Tokens & membership/login

Tags: identityserver3

I have a website where an administrator manages the user accounts (membership), assigns permissions etc. It is built with ASP.NET v4.6, Owin, ASP.NET Identity, Entity Framework & WebApi, with an AngularJS front end. The user logs into a page which (based on the examples on [bitoftech.net](http://bitoftech.net)) calls a token end point and if successful, gets a JWT token, which then authorizes him/her to access the API. It works well.

I'm upgrading to ASP.NET v5, and from what I [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768015/configure-the-authorization-server-endpoint) [tell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546542/token-based-authentication-in-asp-net-5-vnext-refreshed), there is no OAuth2 authorization server middleware that I would need to do this.

Dominick Baier (who I hope reads this!) pointed me to the [AspNet5 sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNet5) for Identity Server v3. From what I can tell:

- There is no 'token end point' - you log in through the Identity Server login: I don't want users to do that.
- You then authorise clients to access your data: I don't want this functionality.

Basically, this is not what I am looking for; this looks like letting users control which apps/clients can access their data/claims, the kind of thing Facebook uses. All I am trying to do is replace a normal Http cookie with a JWT token, because I'm using AngularJS and am using bearer tokens. But every time I research how to do this I end up being pointed to Identity Server V3. So really, my question is, is Identity Server V3 the right tool for what I need, and if so, could you *PLEASE* point me to a working resource/sample/tutorial that shows how this would be done.

Comment: I think you need to pose this as how to solve a specific issue.  Asking if something "is right for you" is nearly-guaranteed to get mod'ed as too-broad / opinion-based

Comment: There is a token endpoint, and consent is optional. check the samples repo (the clients sample)

Comment: Sorry, but which project in the samples solution needs to be running at port 44333?

Comment: Identity server. Use the core repo and run the host