# How to implement the token based authentication in the MVC (Model View Controller) using .net?

Tags: security, authentication, tokenize

I want to understand what token-based authentication means. I searched the internet but couldn't find anything understandable.

**How to implement the token based authentication in the MVC using c#?**

**Steps to implement the token based authentication in MVC 5.**

**Tokenization in MVC**

MVC5 mean (Model View Controller) in .NET

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/30546542/706456?