# ASP.NET 5 Web Api Token Based Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, token, asp.net-core

So, I went through the answer/comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546542/token-based-authentication-in-asp-net-5-vnext-refreshed/33217340#33217340)
and made an exactly similar project in ASP.NET core.
But my Problem is that I have seperate **resource server** project under the same src folder. and although the **[Authorize("Bearer")]** attribute works for the controller methods in the **authorize server** project it does not work in the **resource server** project.

The code would be the same as mentioned on the link above but if required, I could post.

Comment: Indeed please post your code. That will help when the link ever goes down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone would like to know how I solved this issue can read further.

The two projects would generate different private keys, so the **Resource server** would reject the token/public key generated by the **Authorize Server**.

To solve this issue I would basically store the private key generated by the **Auth Server** in a common place(file) and access that key in the Resource Server. So the same key is accessed by both the servers for authorization.