# Add WebAPI to existing aspnetcore MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a new Project, selected ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core), then selected Web Application, Individual User Accounts.

All is good and the project works perfectly, but I want to add WebAPI functionality to this project, so that http://website.com/Home is MVC, and http://website.com/api/whatever is my api, I would like them both to use the same authentication database (so you can register on the MVC site and authenticate to the API).

I do not want to add a second project to the solution if I can avoid it.

Someone posted how to add WebAPI 4 to an existing MVC project but those instructions failed at step 1, add x to the Global.asax, which doesn't exist for an ASP.Net Core MVC Project.

Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your ASP.NET Core `Controller` already supports both MVC and WebAPI. In ASP.NET Core these frameworks were combined together. So all you need is declare a controller action but instead of returning ViewResult return your REST API model.

Example:

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<string> Get()
    {
        return new List<string> { "Hello", "World" };
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("values/{valueName}")]
    public string Get(string valueName)
    {
        return valueName;
    }
}
```

It must be accessible under `GET: /api/values` and `GET /api/values/ + valueName`, depending on configuration. These are most common use cases.

Good luck.

Comment: Well I created my class, added a scaffolding item, set the context etc, and then I got this...
There was an error creating the DbContext instance to get the model. No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Comment: Or, create controller, API Controller with Actions using Entity Framework, set context, same error.

Comment: You were right, just selected the item API Controller with read/write actions, and it did it, thank you :) Answer accepted.

Comment: So how do I access my api then? I tried /api/Tests and it offers to download a json file called Tests.json ??

Comment: How do you authenticate API requests?

Comment: @ShaineFisher did you try in a different browser?

Comment: @AndreiM thanks, sorted using Edge and Chrome instead of IE.

Comment: @bwyn I would assume (not tested) you use the Authorize tag on the method in the controller yopu want to authorize, in my old projecxt I had read as Anon, write as Authorize and Delete and Authorize, Admins. Hoping that ports to this version too.

Comment: @ShaineFisher yes, most likely Authorize will work. You will have to configure your authorization in application Startup class.

Comment: In previous versions of Web Api, the client passed a bearer token to the server for authentication. How are you going to pass credentials to the server?

Comment: At this point, this is an experiment, will let you know tomorrow when I have figured it out.

Comment: @bwyn this may be harder than it looks on paper

Comment: I am having a hard time finding resources for this as well. The following post looks promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546542/token-based-authentication-in-asp-net-5-vnext-refreshed (particularly some of the newer answers), but I have not tried them yet.