# Is it possible to authenticate Web API using OWIN in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, owin

I was searching on Google but I couldn't find whether it's possible to use OWIN token-based authentication in ASP.NET Core. I tried JWT token but my question is -
is it possible to use Katana like we are used to in ASP.NET MVC 5 Web API applications?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Token Based Authentication in ASP.NET Core (refreshed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546542/token-based-authentication-in-asp-net-core-refreshed)