# Using SMS OTP as part of authentication in Identityserver4

Tags: c#, mobile, .net-core, identityserver4

Using Identity Server 4, I'm trying to get started on a solution for a native app to authenticate a user using their mobile number. For example the flow would be:

1. Key-in mobile number
2. Sends SMS with OTP to mobile number
3. Key-in OTP from SMS
4. Get access token (associated to the user)

Can someone point me towards the right direction to implement this.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kes,  Have you been able to figure this one out?

Comment: @BertSinnema, in the end I implemented my own jwt token generation for the process, and ensured the token is the same that is produced by IS4.

Comment: I was thinking of implementing a custom grant type. Anything you can share. Like an example? Cheers

Comment: I did not create my own grant type, but rather just my own actions to request for OTP -> generate the OTP, followed by subsequent action of authenticating with the OTP -> token generation. For the token generation, I referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546542/token-based-authentication-in-asp-net-core-refreshed/33217340#33217340) that guided me along the way.