# JWT Authentication validation in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt

I have followed this link ([Token Based Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048122/token-based-authentication-in-asp-net-core)) to create the jwt token and I am successful to create the token

Below is the image

[image: token creation]

Now I want to validate the token I have passed the token as below

[image: validation of token]

I am getting 401 authorization.Please let me know the where I am doing wrong.

I have taken the same code as mention in the blog

Here is the code link

https://github.com/mrsheepuk/ASPNETSelfCreatedTokenAuthExample

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this line in `TokenController.cs`:

```
 var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
```

you can't just instantiate a new handler for every request. You need to use an handler created using your `JwtBearerOptions` - when you just instantiate you don't use the `signingKey` you placed in `Startup.cs`

```
public TokenController(IOptions<JwtBearerOptions> options)
{
    _bearerOptions = options.Value;
}
```

and in `GetToken`

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = _bearerOptions.SecurityTokenValidators.OfType<JwtSecurityTokenHandler>().First();
```