# How to ConfigureServices Authentication based on routes in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core 1.x I could use authentication methods in ***Configure*** but now in ASP.NET Core 2.0  I have to set everything in ***ConfigureServices*** and can't configure it in  ***Configure*** method. For example

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie()
            .AddXX();
}
```

and then in

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ....
    app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

in the past, I could use something like

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication();
```

and I can't configure it anymore like this.

so how I can use something like this now in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

```
app.Map(new PathString("/MyPath"), i => i.UseMyAuthMethod());
```

Comment: i found an answer from Microsoft guys on github 
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1479#issuecomment-360928524

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In 2.0, the best option to do per-route authentication is to use a custom `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider`:

```cs
    public class CustomAuthenticationSchemeProvider : AuthenticationSchemeProvider
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    
        public CustomAuthenticationSchemeProvider(
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
            IOptions<AuthenticationOptions> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
    
        private async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetRequestSchemeAsync()
        {
            var request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request;
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("The HTTP request cannot be retrieved.");
            }
    
            // For API requests, use authentication tokens.
            if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
            {
                return await GetSchemeAsync(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }
    
            // For the other requests, return null to let the base methods
            // decide what's the best scheme based on the default schemes
            // configured in the global authentication options.
            return null;
        }
    
        public override async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync() =>
            await GetRequestSchemeAsync() ??
            await base.GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync();
    
        public override async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetDefaultChallengeSchemeAsync() =>
            await GetRequestSchemeAsync() ??
            await base.GetDefaultChallengeSchemeAsync();
    
        public override async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetDefaultForbidSchemeAsync() =>
            await GetRequestSchemeAsync() ??
            await base.GetDefaultForbidSchemeAsync();
    
        public override async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetDefaultSignInSchemeAsync() =>
            await GetRequestSchemeAsync() ??
            await base.GetDefaultSignInSchemeAsync();
    
        public override async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetDefaultSignOutSchemeAsync() =>
            await GetRequestSchemeAsync() ??
            await base.GetDefaultSignOutSchemeAsync();
    }
```

Don't forget to register it in the DI container (ideally, as a singleton):

```cs
    // IHttpContextAccessor is not registered by default
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider, CustomAuthenticationSchemeProvider>();
```

Comment: Is there any documentation from Microsoft on this feature?  It seems pretty handy; surprised I don't see anything on the docs site.  We have different security requirements based on a unique customer name in the route.  Being able to dynamically route people to the right authentication provider based on their configuration is pretty useful for that use-case.

Answer (score 11):

**The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/policyschemes?view=aspnetcore-2.2#examples) say what to do if you want to use multiple authentication schemes in ASP.NET Core 2+:**

> The following example enables dynamic selection of schemes on a per
> request basis. That is, how to mix cookies and API authentication:
>
> ```cs
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>     services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
>         .AddCookie(options =>
>         {
>             // For example, can foward any requests that start with /api 
>             // to the api scheme.
>             options.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx => 
>                ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") ? "Api" : null;
>         })
>         .AddYourApiAuth("Api");
> }
> ```

## Example:

I had to implement a mixed-authentication solution in which I needed Cookie authentication for some requests and Token authentication for other requests. Here is what it looks like for me:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        // if URL path starts with "/api" then use Bearer authentication instead
        options.ForwardDefaultSelector = httpContext => httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") ? JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme : null;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
        {
            o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;
            o.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = symmetricKey;
            o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = JwtSignInHandler.TokenAudience;
            o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = JwtSignInHandler.TokenIssuer;
        });
```

where the JWT Bearer authentication is implemented as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29698502/8534588).

## Tips:

One of the biggest 'gotchas' for me was this: Even though the `Cookies` Policy forwards requests with URLs that start with "/api" to the `Bearer` policy, the cookie-authenticated users can still access those URLs if you're using the `[Authorize]` annotation. If you want those URLs to only be accessed through `Bearer` authentication, you must use the `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` annotation on the API Controllers/Actions.