# Openiddict returning 404 instead of 401 for unauthorized web api calls (core 2.0)

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, asp.net-core-webapi, openiddict

I've setup openiddict in a .net core 2.0 web api and have the code and password flows working.  I have test cases to ensure locked down actions in the API get refused when the requestor is not authorized which looks for a 401 status code.

When these tests run, the response is 404 not found instead of 401 which makes my test fail.  I know the route is correct, because it returns 200 when it allows anonymous. I'm getting 404 whenever I try to access any action that is locked down without authentication.   Is this the default status for openiddict when you try to access an resource without being authenticated?  This behavior occurs whether its ran from the browser, from postman, or from the test case.  How do I configure it to return 401?  I have provided my configuration below.

```
services.AddOpenIddict<int>(options =>
{
    options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationContext>();
    options.AddMvcBinders();
    options.EnableAuthorizationEndpoint("/connect/authorize");
    options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");
    options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();
    options.AllowPasswordFlow();
    options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
    options.RequireClientIdentification();
    options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20160));
    options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
 });
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddFacebook(o => { o.ClientId = settings.FacebookAppID; o.ClientSecret = settings.FacebookAppSecret; })
    .AddOAuthValidation();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the desired 401 by specifying the default challenge to oauth.  Would still be nice to know where it was trying to redirect to.

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddFacebook(o => { o.ClientId = settings.FacebookAppID; o.ClientSecret = settings.FacebookAppSecret; })
    .AddOAuthValidation();
```

Comment: `Would still be nice to know where it was trying to redirect to.` -> to the "access denied" page set in the ASP.NET Core Identity options. The behavior you're seeing is caused by the cookies handlers used by Identity - which are configured as the default schemes - and that redirect you instead of returning a 403 response. Since the access denied page doesn't exist in your app, you ultimately get a 404 response.

Comment: (in case my previous comment wasn't clear: this has actually nothing to do with OpenIddict itself).

Comment: That's makes total sense.  Really appreciate you following up with that.  I'm a newbie to openiddict so I didn't know if there was some built in mechanism or something.  By the way...it great to have you monitoring these forums...you've helped me several times...cheers!

Comment: So when I changed the default challenge to OAuth, I got the expected 401 in my tests now.  Interestingly enough, the external login stopped working because the Exchange() method ensure the user is logged in before issuing a token.  Since the default is not the cookie anymore, the user is not automatically logged in from the external login cookie so it fails.  Is the only option here to allow the cookies to be the default scheme and explicitly specify the OAuth scheme on my Authorize attribute in the controllers?  Or is there a way to disable the cookie redirect behavior back to login?

Comment: Actually better yet, maybe the best solution is to override the OnRedirectToLogin event on the cookie defaults to return a 401.

Comment: You may want to try that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464469/how-to-configureservices-authentication-based-on-routes-in-asp-net-core-2-0/46475072#46475072

Comment: That link to create a custom authentication scheme works perfectly.