# Explicitly ignore provided token for Controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, authorization

A little background for this question, we have configured an `OnTokenValidated` event for our preferred Authorization scheme in the following fashion.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(builder =>
        {
            builder.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
                {
                    DoSomething(ctx);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

But there are some Controller actions where we don't want this event to be triggered. However we found that even if the controller has `[AllowAnonymous]`, if a Bearer token is provided, the token will still be verified and this event is triggered.

Is there another mechanism to instruct the ASP.NET Core middleware to skip validating a token, even if it is provided?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57045827/14072498

Comment: Where do you provide the  bearer token, in header or query? It did not trigger the event locally.

Comment: The token is provided in the Authorization header with `Bearer #token`