# Issuing tokens in .NET Core using built in middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, .net-core-authorization

I understand that ASP.NET Core has the assembly [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](http://Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer) which we can use for token validation. However, I just can't quite understand whether ASP.NET Core built-in middleware can be also used to generate the tokens like we did with [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth). Can someone please help me clarify the following questions.

1. Can we generate and issue tokens using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer like we did with Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth like:

   `app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
   app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());`

   without writing custom code to generate the token?
2. If we can't do it with Microsoft.Owin.Security, is there any functionality in [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin/) that is analogous to Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth?

Is using a 3rd party solution like [IdentityServer4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4/) the way to go if we I want to use an in-app user store, expose an endpoint for client to get a token and use it for authorization? Thanks.

Comment: It's a little old now, but we're still using the principles that I describe in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048122/token-based-authentication-in-asp-net-core/33217122#33217122

Comment: Take a look at [Two AuthorizationSchemes in ASP.NET Core 2](https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2) as it covers token generation.

Comment: @MarkG Thanks very much for the link. That's really useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we generate and issue tokens using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer like we did with Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` is just about JWT token validation. And it is not about OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect like it was in `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth`. Moreover according to this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/83) ASP.NET team decided not to port it.

So, to implement `OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect` you defenetly need to use a third-party package.

For basic scenarios it is convinient to use `IdentityServer4` that you mentioned or [`OpenIddict`](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) as an alternative.

For more advanced scenarios I'd prefer [`ASOS`](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server) which is used by `OpenIddict`. BTW, `ASOS` is forked from Katana's OAuth2 authorization server middleware.

As for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin` it is not the same as `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth`. It is just an adapter for running OWIN middleware in an ASP.NET Core application and vice versa

Comment: I think `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` is just about validation.

Comment: @ademcaglin, you are right. In order to create and sign the token you need to use `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package. Thanks for the correction